# Respawn entire launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I learned that respawn Tag in a launch file lets a single node being restarted if it crashes. Further, the required tag if set true, stops the entire launch if a particular important node closes.

Is it also possible to respawn all nodes in a launch file if a particular important node closes and needs to geht respawned?

Thank you for your Help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302335/respawn-entire-launch-file/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it also possible to respawn all nodes in a launch file if a particular important node closes and needs to geht respawned?

No, not as far as I know.

`respawn` is a node-level attribute ([docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2